# Show a caption with a semi-transparent color overlay when hovering over an image

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity

I'm using the following code to show a caption with a semi-transparent red overlay when hovering over an image:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/">
    <div class="thumb">
        <img src="http://www.domain.com/thumbnail.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
        <div>
            <span>Caption</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.thumb {
    position: relative;
}
.thumb div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fe0000;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.thumb img {
    display: block;
}
.thumb div span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.thumb:hover div {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

The problem with this code is that the caption is semi-transparent too. I'm wondering how to change it so the caption is opaque.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: remove .thumb:hover div {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

Comment: But, if I remove that line the background overlay will be opaque, too. I want the overlay to be semi-transparent and the caption opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of giving opacity 0.3 to all the div, you can set

```
background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
```

and then

```
opacity: 1;
```

in the div

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EUUMX/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use background: rgba() instead of #fe0000; in background and you set the opacity to 1. Here is you modified CSS.

CSS:

```
.thumb {
    position: relative;
}
.thumb div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.thumb img {
    display: block;
}
.thumb div span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.thumb:hover div {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a transparent background with `background-color: rgba()` instead of `opacity`

Here is a jsfiddle I just made that will show you this: http://jsfiddle.net/aVz8E/

Answer (score 0):

I give you the solution here :
http://jsfiddle.net/fJ7gs/

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/">
    <div class="thumb">
        <img src="http://www.domain.com/thumbnail.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
        <div class="hover">
            <span class="overlay"></span>
            <span class="caption">Caption</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

.thumb {
    position: relative;
}
.thumb .hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.thumb img {
    display: block;
}
.thumb .caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.thumb:hover .hover {
    opacity:1;
}

.thumb .overlay {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    background: #fe0000;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.thumb:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

I try by changing with color:#000; to be sure because #fff give the impression of transparent in spite it's not.